# Different cusztomizable user profile types

Tags: 6, users

We need to add different customizable user profile fields in Drupal 6.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module is a popular solution for Drupal 6.  It allows you to associate a node with a user, and the node creation process is automated when users are created.  The node is a particular content type, and you can extend it with CCK.  User profiles then get treated mostly like nodes.

For Drupal 7, users are fieldable through the UI (admin/config/people/accounts/fields), so very often an additional module is not needed.  I have run into instances where different profiles are needed, and used [Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating different content types and referencing those contents with different users